What are some (common) materials with compressive strengths around a few 100Pa?
Cometary material was found to have average compressive strengths of no more than ~800 Pa. But to get a better idea of what that really means, I would like to compare it to some (common) material. It is however surprisingly difficult to find any data on that if you don't know what you are looking for. All you typically find are values in the MPa to GPa range (e.g. like here).
So I'm looking for (preferentially academic) references for materials with such compressive strengths.

https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Compressive-strength-density-materials-property-chart-of-different-nano-micro-and_fig4_317614395
